# ASP.net mvc Remote Validation, is it secure? How to secure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I recently came across Remote Validation in [asp.net mvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).  Really helpful feature but doesn't adding something like this to a registration form, say to check for username or email, open up a security hole?  Couldn't someone use this to mine information from the site?  Captca would be an obvious solution to this problem, but has anyone been able to integrate it with the [Remote] validation?

```
public class CreateUserModel : EditUserModel {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Remote("IsUID_Available", "Validation")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
    [Editable(true)]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what kind of security hole have you on mind ? that someone can  identify used usernames by calling remote validation method ? is that really security hole?

Comment: yes, I guess that it is a little paranoid but I'd like to see if there is a way to prevent scripting against it

Comment: The first thing to do is ensure that the controller action being hit by the remote validation call requires authorization so the user has to at least be logged in. Then put logging into the call so that you can at least capture when it's being called and by whom. Don't use remote validation for any data that is deemed sensitive for the application; it really is a convenience method (and it should be noted that **it does not validate server-side**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Captcha if you want. For example with Google's ReCaptcha you could install the  [microsoft-web-helpers](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/microsoft-web-helpers) NuGet, sign up for a [ReCaptcha account](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha) in order to obtain your private/public key pairs and then simply modify your view model so that when you perform the remote call the 2 additional fields are included:

```
public class CreateUserModel : EditUserModel 
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Remote("IsUID_Available", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "recaptcha_response_field,recaptcha_challenge_field", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
    [Editable(true)]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers
@model CreateUserModel
@{
    ReCaptcha.PublicKey = "... public key obtained from Google ...";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserName)
    @ReCaptcha.GetHtml(theme: "red")
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IsUID_Available(string username)
{
    if (!ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "... private key obtained from Google ..."))
    {
        return Json("sorry, please enter a correct Captcha first");
    }

    // TODO: the user entered a correct Captcha => you can proceed
    // into usrname existence verification:
    bool userExists = _repository.UserExists(username);
    return Json(userExists);
}
```